Relation between electric field and polarization at resonance frequency
Assume that we are performing experiments with a low intensity, tunable monochromatic source of electromagnetic radiation, observing the response of an isotropic crystal to it. As the radiation is both low intensity and monochromatic, at very low frequencies we have the linear relation $P=\epsilon_0\chi E$. Does a simple relation like this still hold when the frequency is increased to a resonance frequency? At a resonance frequency, absorption is high and $\chi$ must be complex. But since the intensity is low, do we still have a linear relationship like $P=\epsilon_0\Re(\chi) E$?

If the intensity is indeed low enough, then there is no reason to think otherwise. But since a resonance can increase the polarization magnitude, the level that qualifies as low enough will be lower at the resonance than at surrounding frequencies.

@JosBergervoet, Thanks. I think this answers my question. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

If the intensity is indeed low enough, then there is no reason to think otherwise. But since a resonance can increase the polarization magnitude, the level that qualifies as low enough will be lower at the resonance than at surrounding frequencies.
